# What is the difference between TScrollBar and TControlScrollBar to scroll TForm client area

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, c++builder

I want to draw small bitmaps hold in a list on a **TForm** with **Canvas** but beyond the limit of the size of the **TForm** and use Vertical and Horizontal Scrollers to navigate and allow the user to display the entire area.

I noticed that there are **HorzScrollBar** and **VertScrollBar** **TControlScrollBar** in the **TForm**, but impossible to get them visible or usable, even if they are checked as Visible.

I suppose that they are concerned only with components of the **TForm**, if we resize the **TForm**, they should appear.

Do I have to use external **TScrollBar** (Vertical and Horizontal ones) to achieve the scrolling (by program) of the client area of the **TForm** or is there a way of using the **HorzScrollBar** and **VertScrollBar** **TControlScrollBar**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automatically show the scrollbars when needed (controls outside of the visible area) set `AutoScroll := true;`.

But that requires that you use controls to draw your images. If you want to show the scrollbars even if you only draw (paint) directly on the form canvas, you can do so by setting the `Range` property to the actual extent of your drawn area.

E.g.

```
procedure TForm24.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.HorzScrollBar.Range := 1000;
end;
```

So, to answer your question, you can use the built-in scrollbars.

Comment: thanks, I can also change the Range in the properties of the **TForm**